# Automatically map object when retreiving data from database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am developing project, where database repository is coded like this:

```
public List<UserDTO> ShowAll()
{
    return OnConnect<List<UserDTO>>(db =>
    {
        IEnumerable<User> users = db.Users;

        return users.
            ToListUserDTO();
    });
}

public List<AnotherUserDTO> ShowAll()
{
    return OnConnect<List<AnotherUserDTO>>(db =>
    {
        IEnumerable<User> users = db.Users;

        return users.
            ToAnotherUserDTO();
    });
}

public TReturn OnConnect<TReturn>(Func<BankManagerDockAuthorizationEntitiesWrapper, TReturn> action)
{
    TReturn result = default(TReturn);

    OnConnect(db =>
        {
            result = action(db);
        });

    return result;
}
```

Now, If I want to get only user's id from database I Have to create another method which will run `ToUsersWithJustIdDTO()`. Of fourse I can do something like this:

```
var users = repo.ShowAll()
    .Select(x => new UserViewModel
    {
        Id = x.Id
    })
    .ToList();
```

but `ShowAll()` will run huge sql query and get everything about User. Thats not good.

The best solution for me would be to create generic method `ShowAll` which `T` type and `users` will be automatically mapped to that `T` type, something like this:

```
IEnumerable<UserViewModel> users1 = repo.ShowAll<UserViewModel>();
IEnumerable<AnotherUserViewModel> users1 = repo.ShowAll<AnotherUserViewModel>();
```

But I dont really know how to do it. What I managed is to retreive `IQueryable` from repository and then do select, like this:

```
public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
{
    return OnConnect<IQueryable<User>>(db =>
    {
        return db.Users;
    });
}
```

and usage:

```
    var users = repo.GetUsers() // its IQueryable, so query is not launched yet
    .Select(x => new UserViewModel
    {
        Id = x.Id,
    })
    .ToList();
```

Now it should run just `SELECT Id from Users`.. but thats not working. I cant do that: context is closed after `GetUsers` and I cant do `Select`. What else can I do?

Comment: @TheGeneral I think it is possible to pass `T` type which will automatically map `db.Users` to that type and prevent making a huge sql query. I am pretty sure that is possible, but I dont really know how to do it.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [AutoMapper - Queryable Extensions](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html). Basically you define mappings between the DB entities and ViewModels, which can be translated by LINQ2SQL.

Comment: Today you need only `Id` and you adding new method to repository for it. Tomorrow you will need another projection, and will create another method... Imho, it is time to think, does it really necessary to use repository?! Because using such repositories is meaningless overhead.